# geoserver heatmap tiles doesn't display well (with leaflet)

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, sld

I am trying to display a heatmap [generated with geoserver](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation) on my map using the [L.tileLayer.WMS class from Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms), but the tiles do not fit well together.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Does it show up correctly in the geoserver layer preview?

Comment: I can preview my points but I don't find how to preview with the sld (my heatmap)

Comment: Ok I found how to do, here is a screenshot of my preview : https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3zsmm/njas
It seems ok

Comment: I don't use geoserver but it seems to me that the problem lies in some tiling settings that are in conflict with your wms or leaflet itself. I'd better if you post some code.

Comment: can you try on the geoserver preview to ask for a tiled view? expand the options (button on top of the directions pad) and ask for the tiles (see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/6YOWQvS.png)). Does it renders equal to "non-tiled" layer?

Comment: Effectively I get the same problem with a tiled view https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3zsmm/oas2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it was a tile problem, as said in the geoserver doc

> Rendering transformations may not work correctly in tiled mode, unless they have been specifically written to accomodate it.

but setting tiled to false didn't work.

But I found this custom leaflet class which worked for me : http://bl.ocks.org/ismyrnow/5415445

Comment: Where does one set tiled=false?

Answer (score 5):

I've had this issue before, it looks like you have done exactly what I did.

The GeoServer WPS example heat map  doesn't support tiles, so what Gery said is correct you need to set tiled=false.

I had the same problem in OpenLayers, so it isn't a Leaflet issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the case the code of the WMS class itself would be the problem, you can check this nice heatmap example by Patrick Wied to see if you find a relevant difference with your code: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html

Comment: I already tried this great API and it worked well but I changed for a server side computed heatmap for performance reasons.

Comment: that means that geoserver is complicating things here, does it have any log error or something like that from where some debugging can be done? what does firebug (net tab) says?

Comment: Here is my Geoserver query log : http://justpaste.it/e07d
No log error on the client side

Comment: looks to me that you need to change things to, e.g.: tiled=false, and check the projection stuff in your map as well as the tile size (not likely but give it a try). If your basemaps are google et al (basemaps in 900913) and your tiles in 4326, things are messed up because of that.